# Accessing Facebook events in groups through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook's API. I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API to access the event data of a group (not a page).

I'm using a Facebook app to make the API calls via a simple Perl script. I can see the events exist in the groups when I visit the group on Facebook with my browser. But the events are not getting returned by the API call. I just get `{"data":[]}` returned. My Perl script works fine with API calls for public pages.

Is it possible to get access to the group event data via the API? If so, how? If not, is there some other way I can get access like making the API calls using my user account on Facebook?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=blah&client_secret=blah&grant_type=client_credentials');

my $access_token = $response->decoded_content;

my $json = $ua->get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/WestfieldCulturalDistrict/events?' . $access_token);
print Dumper $json->decoded_content;
```

Comment: please add your code to the question. also, are you using a user token of a group member to access the events?

Comment: added code. Like I said, though, it works fine for public pages. I don't really have an issue with the code. No, I am using an app token to try to access the events.

Comment: there is a very big difference between pages (they are always public) and groups...anyway, the docs specifically say that you need a user token to access group events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/group/events

> A user access token for a member of the group with user_groups permission.
>
> ...
>
> By default this will only return events within the last two weeks, use until or since parameters to modify this range.

There is no `user_groups` permission anymore, i guess that´s why there is an important message on that page:

> This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.5.

So either that´s a bug in the Facebook docs, or it´s just not possible anymore to get group events. Not even with a User Token. You should try with one though (and `user_managed_groups`).